# Kotlin scoping functions: Android EditText supports *apply*, *let* and *run* but not *with*

Tags: kotlin

I have an Activity that holds a EditText. Imported via:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.myActivity.*
```

I would like to use the `with` function but for some reason only the other scoping function are accessible:

[image: apply, also, run, runCatching, takeIf and takeUnless are shown, but not with]

`apply`, `also`, `run`, `runCatching`, `takeIf` and `takeUnless` are shown, but not `with` (and yes, I scrolled further down and even typed it out. Its marked as unknown if I do so).

To clarify, here what actually happens:

[image: Unresolved reference: with]

Are there rules to when an object has these functions and when not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `apply`, `also`, `run`, `runCatching`, `takeIf` and `takeUnless` are extensions, when `with` is function with 2 parameters. [Here](https://ask.ericlin.info/post/2017/06/subtle-differences-between-kotlins-with-apply-let-also-and-run/) is good article about this.

You can use `with` like this:

```
with(editText) {
    //your code
}
```

But you can not call `with`, as you tried to do this:

```
editText.with() //compilation error
```

**Update**:
`with` function purpose is to call object methods more easy, you don't need to write something like this:

```
someObject.a();
someObject.b();
someObject.c();
//etc
```

When you use `with`, you can write it like this:

```
with(someObject) {
    a();
    b();
    c();
    //etc
}
```

Comment: I understand that. I wasn't confused about how to call it but about the fact that I *couldnt* call it.

Comment: @Smogen you can call it as I wrote above. I updated answer

Comment: I attached a screenshot to clarify

Comment: @Smogen it seems, you does not understand how this function works. Let me clarify it in answer and also read article from my answer

Comment: Ah, got it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting any suggestions about **with** function because, it has no source type as extension, while other extensions contains source attached to it. How?

Look at the difference below :

**with** function

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R {
    ...
    return receiver.block()
}
```

**let** function

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    ...
    return block(this)
}
```

Here `T` is the source type for the extension.